# Changing underline color of TextInputEditText not working inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-textinputlayout

My target is to **programmatically change the hint label and underline color in a focused TextInputEditText**. After some time I finally got both working in a test enviroment but when implemented in my real app the underline suddently stopped working. I narrowed it down to the ScrollView.

I tried messing with focus in the ScrollView, TextInputEditField and TextInputLayout but none worked.

To change the color im simply using the BackgroundTintList:

```
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled},
    };

    int[] colors = new int[] {
            Color.CYAN,
            Color.BLUE,
    };

    ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

    ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(edit, myList);
```

The test app for reproduction: 
https://github.com/guiquintelas/textinputedittext-underline-color

Some imgs:

[image: Outside ScrollView]

[image: Inside ScrollView]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to change the edit text color
TRY THIS

use backgroundTint to change change the color

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Underline color change"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
```

Comment: sorry but im trying to change the color of TextInputEditText programmatically

Answer (score 0):

To Programmatically change the color of TextInputEditText use it's `setBackgroundTintList` method or `setsetSupportBackgroundTintList` for pre-lollipop

```
 editText.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#F00000")));
```